# Split screen and resize on ffmpeg streams

Tags: ffmpeg, resize, scale, rtsp

I want get h264 streams from IP cameras, resize it, combine to grid, and restream or save to file. I succesfull split streams and save, but I don't know how can I resize streams. Becouse this streems are large, ffmpeg go to 100% cpu, loss frames and crach. Please tell me how can I resize this streams before combine and save ?? Thank for your help and time.

This is my cli

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i "rtsp://admin:Pass@192.168.88.76:554/h264" -rtsp_transport tcp -i "rtsp://admin:Pass@192.168.88.76:554/h264" -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]hstack" -c:v libx264 combo.avi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [scale filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) with the [hstack](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hstack) and [vstack](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hstack) filters. Since all of your inputs are the same size you can do it like this for a 2x2 grid:

```
"[0:v][1:v]hstack[top];[2:v][3:v]hstack[bottom];[top][bottom]vstack,scale=iw/2:-2"
```

Alternatively, you could scale (and/or pad, crop, etc) each input then use the stack filters. This is useful if your inputs are not the same size:

```
"[0:v]scale=1024:-1[v0];[1:v]scale=1024:-1[v1];[2:v]scale=1024:-1[v2];[3:v]scale=1024:-1[v3];[v0][v1]hstack[t];[v2][v3]hstack[b];[t][b]vstack"
```

Comment: Thank you for write! I try your way and I have some errors - please see my command and output https://pastebin.com/x0Uh2NUT. Can you help me ?

Comment: @lukas.gab Was the output file still playable?

Comment: Ok, this work on my bare metal machine, but on KVM with Windows no - this must be performance problem. I can run this on bare metal and this is ok. But may you write filter for 4/6 screens in grid, I can't understand how can I add more screens.

Comment: Ok, I make some command and I have 4 split screen but after few second ffmpeg crash. Can you see on my input and output ? https://pastebin.com/J9sjeSNw